# Accelerated Dragon, Modern Bc4 Variation (B35) 10.Ndb5!

Tags: opening, sicilian-defense, 1.e4, accelerated-dragon

After:

```
[FEN ""]
1.e4 c5 2.Nf3 Nc6 3.d4 cxd4 4.Nd4 g6 5.Nc3 Bg7 6.Be3 Nf6 7.Bc4 O-O 8.Bb3 a5 9.O-O d6
```

It appears 10.Ndb5 is difficult for Black to play against.  I only found some games from 2008.  Is it still the case that Black is avoiding this line at high levels?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line 8.Bb3 a5 9.0-0 d6 still occasionally occurs in games of IMs and GMs, and the results are actually quite ok for black. For example, [Hou Yifan-Yu Yangyi](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1667437), [Kudrin-Diamant](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1670609), [Vishnu-Vazquez Igarza](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1750258) and [Saric-Damaso](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1785731).

However, at the highest level, it indeed seems that black is looking for alternatives. At the latest FIDE Grand Prix, Palma de Mallorca 2017, Gelfand tried 8....d5 against [Vachier-Lagrave](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1891835) and 8....d6 against [Vallejo Pons](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1891866), but lost both games.

A remarkable alternative is 8....Re8, first played by [Zvjaginsev](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1733369) in 2013. This move has been repeated in several GM games, e.g. [Leko-Vitiugov](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1773221) and [Sanal-Dubov](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1890765).
**EDIT:** In the first round of the Gashimov Memorial 2018, the theoretical discussion on 8....Re8 is continued in the game [Navara-Mamedov](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1918248).

Recently, a new repertoire book has been published: [The Hyper Accelerated Dragon](http://www.thinkerspublishing.com/raja-panjwani-th-e-hyper-accelerated-dragon-2017.html) by IM Raja Panjwani. According to a book review on [Canadian Chess Newsfeed](http://chess.ca/newsfeed/node/963), the author analyzes two variations against 7.Bc4.

> If White avoids the Maroczy (c2-c4), then the only other way to stop the ...d7-d5 equalizer is 7.Bc4, which is the subject of Chapters 2 and 3. Black could allow the game to transpose into a Yugoslav attack (Bc4, f3, Qd2, 000, and a kingside pawn storm) but Raja wants to avoid that, and offers two antidotes: 7...Qa5 (ch.2) and his own system ("My System") which is a hybrid of the Dragon on the kingside (e7, f7, g6, h7/h5) and a Taimanov on the queenside (...a6, ...b5, ...e6). That's the subject of Chapter 3, and the excerpt in the game player below.

```
      [StartPly "15"]

      [FEN ""]
      1.e4 c5 2.Nf3 Nc6 3.d4 cxd4 4.Nxd4 g6 5.Nc3 Bg7 6.Be3 Nf6 7.Bc4 O-O 8.Bb3 a5 (8...d5)(8...d6)(8...Re8) 9.O-O d6
```

Comment: Thanks for all the info!  Of the games you linked only one has the critical 10.Ndb5 and I prefer Whites position -- though Kudrin made a tactical oversight with 22.Nc7? 8...Re8 is interesting.

Comment: You're welcome! Although I didn't look at it in detail, I like the subtile 8....Re8. Against 9.f3 black can play 9....e6 and 10....d5, while after 9.0-0 black seems also fine after 9....d6 and 10....Na5. Btw, 8....a5 9.0-0 d6 10.Ndb5 was also played in Saric - Damaso.